# Would you count following scenario as (dangerous) CSRF?

Tags: security, xss, csrf

Imagine you have a big cooperation. Now someone found CSRF vulnerability which only works through the own site (since the site is protected by checking the Referer-Header, no CSRF token). This can perform critical actions, but only if the request comes from your site. That means a small XSS attack could perform bigger actions through this vulnerability. Would you count this as a critical vulnerability and should this be rewarded as a CSRF attack?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not directly programming related. // How unreliable the referrer is, should be common knowledge – so if part of your “security” is based on it, that is bad news already.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've found a vulnerability in a big cooperation that has exactly this scenario. Are there other ways to perform the attack except of XSS or using the weaknesses of old browsers? I just want to prepare myself for question they may ask (if they ask any or decide to decline a reward). 
Edit:
Are they really that unreliable. I've searched online and found multiple sources that said it's fine, but not the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [On Site Request Forgery](http://blog.portswigger.net/2007/05/on-site-request-forgery.html).

An XSS vulnerability always trumps any CSRF/OSRF attack. Just think, if the forms were not protected by referer but were protected by a token, the XSS attack could simply read the token out of the DOM and then submit the form.

Therefore there is no extra risk to the site. The only exception to this is where you have an [Open Redirect Vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) in combination with an unsafe action implemented as a GET.

Say the following URL is available:

```
https://example.com/delete_my_account
```

The handler validates referer to ensure that the request comes from `https://example.com/*`.

However, there is also another URL available that issues JavaScript redirects:

```
https://example.com/redirect_to_site
```

This would be called as follows within the site to track external links:

```
https://example.com/redirect_to_site?https://google.com
```

However a OSRF attack would be possible by constructing a CSRF attack redirecting to something like the following:

```
https://example.com/redirect_to_site?https://example.com/delete_my_account
```

Because referer is checked, this will validate the request because only `delete_my_account` is checking the referer here as this is deemed the unsafe action. However, because it can be redirected over the unprotected handler, it can defeat the referer protection.

Therefore, unless there is such functionality on the site or unless the site allows user content to construct such links, there is no vulnerability in checking referer for CSRF protection.

*Note:* Before anyone mentions that the referer header can be spoofed, this would only be possible from the attacker's own connection. In a CSRF attack you need this to be spoofed on the victim's connection - CSRF is an attack against another user - therefore although refererer is a weak protection, it is still adequate in many cases.